# why is $E = [0, \frac{1}{2})$ open in $S = [0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Since $S$ \ $ E = [1/2, 1)$ is not closed, isn't $E$ not open?

Comment: Because $E=S\cap \left(-1,\frac 1 2\right)$ and $\left(-1,\frac 1 2\right)$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: It is open in the subspace topology. I suggest you read up on this topic. It's a bit strange at first, but the best way to think about it is as if the rest of the real line doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. $S$ inherits the subspace-topology from $\mathbb R$. Any set $U \subseteq S$ is open, iff $U = \hat U \cap S$ for some open $\hat U \subseteq \mathbb R$. You can show that thus any set is closed in $S$ iff its of the form $\hat A \cap S$ for some $ \hat A \subseteq \mathbb R$ which is closed (in $\mathbb R$).

Now, clearly, $E = (-\infty, 1/2) \cap S$ is open in $S$, since $(-\infty, 1/2)$ is open in $\mathbb R$. (You could have - in fact - chosen any other lower bound between $0$ and $-\infty$.) And moreover, $S \setminus E = [1/2,1)$ is closed in $S$, because $[1/2,1) = [1/2, 2] \cap S$ and $[1/2, 2]$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is open in $S$ iff $\:\forall\: x\in E\:\exists\: \varepsilon>0:(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S\subseteq E$. Take $\varepsilon=\min\left(x,\frac12-x\right)$ and you're done for $x>0$. For $x=0$, take $\varepsilon=\frac12$ and you're done.